# Переполнение буфера при помощи "jmp esp" в gnu/linux

Tags: linux, ассемблер

Я пытаюсь написать программу для переполнения буфера в ОС *gnu/linux*.

В одной статье, посвящённой этой проблеме, нашла следующий способ:

```
[мусор]+[адрес инструкции jmp/call esp]+[шеллкод]
```

Дизассемблирование уязвимой программы не помогает.

Каким образом можно найти адрес инструкции `jmp %esp` в *gnu/linux*?

Comment: *Дизассемблирование уязвимой программы не помогает* — как дизассемблируете?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

по [вот этой инструкции](https://penturalabs.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/vulnerability-development-buffer-overflows-how-to-bypass-full-aslr/) собрал бинарник на 32-битной системе (на 64-битной ошибка: `Error: operand type mismatch for 'jmp'`, см. обновление ниже).

текст программы:

```
$ cat vuln.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// hard coded jmp *esp function ;-)
void jmpesp()
{
        __asm__("jmp *%esp");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char buffer[100];
        strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
        printf("buffer: [%s].\n", buffer);
        return 0;
}
```

сборка бинарника `vuln`:

```
$ gcc vuln.c -o vuln -ggdb -fno-stack-protector -z execstack
```

а вот она, инструкция:

```
$ objdump -d vuln | grep 'ff e4'
 804844f:       ff e4                   jmp    *%esp
```

---

**обновление**

на 64-битной системе, видимо, вместо `esp` следует использовать `rsp`:

```
        __asm__("jmp *%rsp");
```

тогда сборка проходит удачно. и инструкция присутствует:

```
$ objdump -d vuln | grep 'ff e4'
  40054a:   ff e4                   jmpq   *%rsp
```

Comment: огромное спасибо Вам!))